# how to keep data created in the ready method? Django production vs test database

Tags: django

As you know django give you clear database in testing, but I have a [`ready()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/applications/#for-application-authors) method that create some data for me and I need to query these data in my tests.

```
class YourAppConfig(AppConfig):
    default_auto_field = 'django.db.models.AutoField'
    name = 'Functions.MyAppsConfig'
    def ready(self):
        from django.contrib.auth.models import Permission
        from django import apps
        from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType

       try:
          Permission.objects.get_or_create(....)
          MyOtherModel.objects.get_or_create(....)
      except:
          pass
```

```
class TestRules(APITestCase):

    def test_my_model(self):
        ....
        x = MyOtherModel.objects.filter(....).first()
        # x = None # <=========== problem is here ========= I need to see the data that I created in the ready method
        ....
```

Comment: You need `setup` - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/testing/overview/#writing-tests. There is also `setupclass`

Comment: Take a look at this answer I've just added to another question where data is created during tests; https://stackoverflow.com/a/68163463/1199464

Answer (score 0):

You can use the fixtures for that, in each Test case you can fixtures to it as stated [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/testing/tools/#transactiontestcase) example is

```
class Test(TransactionTestCase):
    fixtures = ['user-data.json']
    def setUp():
       …
```

Django will load the fixtures before under test case

Comment: how to use the fixtures for that.?

Comment: Sorry for that, i was in a hurry, check updated answer