# Django Test Object created is empty

Tags: python, django, django-testing, django-tests

I am trying to follow instructions from the Django documentation:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/testing/overview/

However when I try to create the object for the test. The object is empty??

This is my code:

```
from django.test import TestCase, Client
from django.urls import reverse
from .models import ShortURL
from .views import generate_shortURL, redirect, home
from datetime import datetime

url = "https://stackoverflow.com/"
time = datetime.now()

class TestURLShortener(TestCase):
    def setup(self):
        self.client = Client()
        obj= ShortURL.objects.create(original_url=url, short_url='zqSkSQ', time_date_created=time, count=2)
        obj.save()



   def test_creating_short_URL_POST(self):
         """
         Test to create short Urls
         """
         short_url_from_db = ShortURL.objects.all()
         print(f'short_url_from_db : {short_url_from_db}')

         response = self.client.post(reverse('generate_shortURL'), data={'original_url': url})

         generated_short_url = response.context["chars"] 

         self.assertEquals(generated_short_url, 'afasdf')
```

This is the results when I run the test:

`short_url_from_db` prints out this `<QuerySet []>` instead of the object I wanted it to print out from the setup function.

How can I get the object I created to use in this test?

Comment: Watch out, you are using `setup` instead of  `setUp`

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `setUp` and not `setup` as the function for setting up your test case.

You also don't need to call `save()` if you use `create()`.

An alternative you could make use of is [`setUpTestData()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.TestCase.setUpTestData)

> This technique allows for faster tests as compared to using `setUp()`.

```
    class TestURLShortener(TestCase):

        @classmethod
        def setUpTestData(cls):
            # Set up data for the whole TestCase
            cls.obj = ShortURL.objects.create(original_url=url, short_url='zqSkSQ', time_date_created=time, count=2)
            ...

        def setUp(self):
            self.client = Client()
  
       def test_obj_type(self):

             self.assertTrue(isinstance(self.obj, ShortURL))
```